# Dygraphs change date format

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am trying to make a small school proyect which requires me to graph some data onto a small webpage. As I am not located in the US the standar date format used here is Day/Month/Year and all my data is linked to a date with this format, however, I understand by default, dygraph uses the american Month/Day/Year format, is there any way to change this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hope this link is useful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085781/x-axis-date-format-dygraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Dygraphs, but I can help with pure JavaScript.

So you want to take a string like "03/17/2002" and change it to "17/03/2002".
You can `split()` the string.

```
function AmerToStan(date) {
  var dateArray = date.split("/");
  var month = dateArray[0];
  var day = dateArray[1];
  var year = dateArray[2];
  return (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}
```

I haven't tested that, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Hope this helped.